# Add columns to query without changing the results of the existing query

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that looks like this

```
WITH A   -- Get a list of unique combinations of Shipmentnumber and ShipmentType
AS  (
SELECT Distinct
      f_Shipmentnumber
 ,    f_ShipmentType
FROM  t_shipment, t_pilot where t_Pilot.f_ProviderID='11' and f_date >='2016-01-01' and f_date <='2017-01-01'
)
,   B  -- Get a list of all those shipmentnumbers values that have more than one shipmentType associated
AS  (
SELECT f_Shipmentnumber
FROM   A
GROUP BY
       f_Shipmentnumber
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT 
     A.f_Shipmentnumber,
    A.f_ShipmentType
```

This returns exactly what I need but now I need to add more a few more columns such as date, pilotID and a couple others. When I try to add them it changes the amount of rows returned. How can I do add them without throwing off my results.

Here is a small sample of the data returned.

```
f_Shipmentnumber    f_ShipmentType
   22060    1
   22494    2
   22494    1
   22620    2
   22620    1
   22844    1
   22844    2
   23528    1
   23528    2
   286084   1
   286084   2
   286104   2
   286104   1
```

The table has a lot of columns but I would like to just return the above data and the other data that goes with it. e.g.   f_Shipment_ID, f_date, f_Pilot_ID,  f_imo. f_shipment_ID is unique. I hope this gives you a better idea what I'm trying to do.

I have done a little more work on it and I'm getting closer here is what I have now.

```
WITH A   -- Get a list of unique combinations of Shipmentnumber and          ShipmentType
AS  ( 
 SELECT Distinct
 f_Shipmentnumber, f_ShipmentType, f_Shipment_ID, f_date, f_Pilot_ID,   f_SailedFrom, f_SailedTo
  FROM  t_shipment 
  join t_Pilot pilot on pilot.f_PilotID=t_shipment.f_Pilot_ID 
where pilot.f_ProviderID='11' and t_shipment.f_date >='2016-01-01' and    t_shipment.f_date <='2017-01-01'
)
,   B  -- Get a list of all those shipmentnumbers values that have more than  one shipmentType associated
AS  (
SELECT f_Shipmentnumber
FROM   A
GROUP BY
       f_Shipmentnumber
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT 
     A.f_Shipment_ID, A.f_Pilot_ID, A.f_Shipmentnumber
,    A.f_ShipmentType, A.f_date, f_SailedFrom, f_SailedTo
FROM    A
JOIN B
    ON  A.f_Shipmentnumber = B.f_Shipmentnumber
```

Here is a sample of the data returned.

```
f_Shipment_ID   f_Pilot_ID  f_Shipmentnumber    f_ShipmentType  f_date  f_SailedFrom    f_SailedTo
198084  216 286506  2   2016-01-05 11:00:00.000 Kadetrenden 1   Skagen 3 -- P/B
198504  1   286506  2   2016-01-05 11:00:00.000 Kadetrenden 1   Skagen 3 -- P/B
200266  77  286511  1   2016-01-07 10:00:00.000 Langeland T -- P/B  Skagen 3 -- P/B
198538  275 286511  2   2016-01-08 11:00:00.000 Kadetrenden 1   Skagen 3 -- P/B
198130  160 286524  1   2016-01-07 02:00:00.000 Korsør -- P/B   Nyborg Havn
198134  120 286524  1   2016-01-06 04:00:00.000 Langeland H -- P/B  Nyborg -- P/B
199111  45  286524  1   2016-01-06 03:00:00.000 Langeland H -- P/B  Nyborg -- P/B
198081  271 286531  2   2016-01-06 05:00:00.000 Korsør -- P/B   Alfa/4 -- P/B
```

At this point I would just like to show just the rows with duplicate shimpmentNumbers and different shipment types which is what I was getting before I added the extra fields. The dupe shipmentNumbers with the same shipmenttype need to go. Thank You!!

Comment: You would start by providing us some information about your tables and what you are trying to do. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Meanwhile you might want to take a look at this article and start using ANSI-92 style joins. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: I have a table called shipment and it has the f_shipment number field which can be used multiple times for a pilotage, but the company accidentally started reusing the shipmentnumbers, So I can no longer count pilotages by using the distinct clause, so I need to check where the shipment types are different and the dates.

Comment: Maybe you're not formulating the correct question, add your table schema, sample data and desired result.

Comment: @SeanLange From the in-line comments in the query, I'm guessing that the reason Robert is not using ANSI-92 style joins is because he actually wants a Cartesian join.

Comment: Adding extra fields into the `A` query is quite likely to increase the number of rows returned - the more fields you add in, the more likely it is that several rows that were previously only contributing one DISTINCT row to your final output will now have something that distinguishes them and causes them to give you two or more rows instead. Can you give table structures, sample data, revised query that you've tried (with the extra fields) and expected results.

Comment: You probably want to add a cross apply statement to your query but its hard to write one without more details.

Comment: @Skippy I kind of guessed that myself. But they would better using an explicit cross join.

Comment: Unless you are willing to provide details about your query there is nothing anybody can do to help. You have shown us a query that doesn't quite work and you have shown us the desired output. But we don't know what your data looks like. And the query you posted is incomplete. You have a cte and a partial query after that. This really would be simple if you posted enough details for us to help.

Comment: In a Management Studio session I'd recommend creating some table variables and breaking your SQL up into small chunks which you insert into the table variables. Then you can select the contents of the table variables to see what is going on. Once you have the smaller parts working you can write more SQL joining the table variables together, just like normal tables, until you have the solution.